# Propagate provided dependency to dependent project

Tags: java, maven

I have simple Maven project structure:

```
mainProject
|-- subProject1
|   |-- subSubProject
|-- subProject2
```

The point is that I have mainProject which contains dependencies used in each of subProjects (those dependencies are common for each subproject), but I don't want them to be included in my WAR file at the end when it's compiled and built (scope provided). Also, I don't want to declare dependencies in each of the subprojects since I already declared them in mainProject.

WAR file include all subproject libs in it's built files.

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe your problem and what you want in more detail? What have you tried that doesn't do this already?

Comment: the mainProject is just a simple parent pom that holds dependencies for the other subprojects? It's a bit vague what you're asking.

Comment: Are those 3rd party jars or your internal project specific jars. ? - Thanks

Comment: Each project is a jar and has own dependencies. mainProject is just a "common" project, with helper classes used as dependency through all other subprojects. Also mainProject contains dependencies required in subProject1, subSubProject, subProject2 and every other subProject (shared dependencies). I declared these dependencies as scope=provided, since I don't want them to be placed in my webapp WEB-INF/lib folder (too many of them), but they are required by other subProjects. Scope provided doesn't allow propagation of dependencies and I'm searching for a way to bypass that.

Comment: the easiest of managing different kind of dependencies and their versions is to have a parent pom.xml that holds information of the other subprojects, specify in each subproject the dependencies that are necessary and inherit the version from the parent pom. Let me know if you need more info on how to do this

Comment: Once again, why `provided` does not work for you?

Comment: provided does not support propagation to subprojects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there can be two solution for this problem.

1.) You can changed the scope to compile and while building the war file you can exclude all those jars that you don't want in your war file using maven-war-plugin like this.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/xyz.jar</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

2.) If they are 3rd party specific jars then you can move them to server lib directory and at the run time your web container will provide the required classes.

Comment: 1. There is too many of them to create this exclude configuration. I was thinking about that but project is constantly growing and eventually I would lost the the track of those dependencies.

2. Those 3rd party jars are stored somewhere else and loaded within the container by VirtualWebappLoader

Comment: Thanks @tech-idiot, I managed to solve the problem by using packagingIncludes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with Maven, but I remember seeing parent poms listed in a file poms I've worked with. It seems you like you include your main project pom as a parent pom, and then also add the subproject-specific dependencies in their respective poms. I *think* the scope=provided in the parent pom will still keep the common dependencies from being the war file at the end.